# How do you host a site with multiple index on Digital Ocean Apps

Tags: html, web, digital-ocean, web-hosting, digital-ocean-apps

I was trying to figure out how to get a training site setup on digital ocean apps. I adjusted the HTTP Request Routes however I could never get my html pages to render.

Git ->

```
/static/training01/index.html
/static/training02/index.html
```

However when it set the App source directory to -> /static

Then the routes to ->

```
/training01
/training02
```

The content would not show up and I couldn't load the page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating the following file structure.

git ->

```
static/index.html
static/training01/index.html
static/traingin02/index.html
```

Output ->

```
/static
```

Routes ->

```
/
```

Then I have to have href to the trainings ->

```
my.site.app/training01/index.html
my.site.app/training02/index.html
```